# Install packages behind proxy using saltatack

Tags: salt-stack

Getting through a Saltstack tutorial and ran into a problem how to install packages on a linux host if it's behind a proxy.
For example, I have a file nettools.sls:

```
install_network_packages:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - rsync
      - lftp
      - curl
```

How can I pass env variables like `http_proxy` so to install packages?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it worked for me:

```
proxy:
  environ.setenv:
    - name: Proxy Settings
    - value:
        http_proxy: http://10.20.80.50:3128
        https_proxy: https://10.20.80.50:3128

install_network_packages:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - rsync
      - lftp
      - curl
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a state or add it to this state to configure the server to use HTTP_PROXY before running these packages. See the following document on configuration of this:

https://www.shellhacks.com/linux-proxy-server-settings-set-proxy-command-line

Also see this article from Salt:
https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.proxy.html